SAMBA password expiration

RHEL-8.10 to be specific
samba-4.19
security = user in /etc/samba/smb.conf [global]
passdb backend = tdbsam in /etc/samba/smb.conf [global]

smbpasswd -a <user> is done so there is an independent password for samba connections.
When a Linux user's password in /etc/passwd is expired, is there a way to also make the samba password expired for the given user?  At the very least dissallow the samba connection for the given user when their Linux account password is expired?
scenario: the /etc/passwd password is set to expire in 90 days, per PASS_MAX_DAYS in /etc/login.defs and as shown by passwd -S <user>.  When a user has gone more than 90 days and the time to change their Linux password has come and gone and they are effectively locked out of Linux, I am observing (with a test account) that samba access to shared folders is still available because their windowsNT password is on a different expiration cycle, and they can still access samba shares of the Linux server.  I want /etc/passwd expiration to also expire the samba password on the linux server if possible.  Ideally make PASS_MAX_DAYS also apply to the samba password and force the user to update, is this possible?  This is basic stuff today for the /etc/passwd password, but it seems like samba fell through the cracks on this.

Start by enabling the obey pam restrictions option in your smb.conf. Even though Samba cannot use PAM for authentication (due to not receiving a cleartext password from client), it can still use PAM for authorization, that is, access checks, as well as session setup.
Enabling this option will cause the account (authorization) and session modules to be processed from /etc/pam.d/samba. The distro defaults should include pam_unix as an account module, which in this section handles both account expiry and password expiry checks according to /etc/shadow:
account required pam_unix.so


works.  fwiw /etc/pam.d/samba contains account include password-auth and that password-auth contain a account required pam_unix.so
